# Incorrect time/time zone after sorting, grouping, and reindexing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timezone

I get incorrect time zone/ time combination after performing a sort and group by on a dataframe with a timeindex column.

```
df['datetimeInd'][0]
Out[645]: Timestamp('1997-05-11 09:19:40.050000-0400', tz='US/Eastern')

df['datetimeInd'][0].tz
Out[646]: <DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>

df = df.sort_values(by = 'seconds', ascending = True).groupby('date', as_index = False).first()

df['datetimeInd'][0]
Out[648]: Timestamp('1997-05-11 13:19:40.050000-0400', tz='US/Eastern')
```

The time changes back to UTC, while the time zone stays at 'US/Eastern'. Am I doing something incorrectly, or is this a bug?

Comment: what's your pandas version this maybe a bug that has been recently fixed

Comment: Pandas version is 0.18.1